# Properties File is not working

Tags: java, properties

When i run my programm, i get this errorlog:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at Manuals.<init>(Manuals.java:62)
    at Manuals.main(Manuals.java:479)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Manuals.getProjects(Manuals.java:372)
    at Delete.<init>(Delete.java:27)
    at Manuals.run(Manuals.java:90)
    at Manuals.main(Manuals.java:479)
```

This are lines, where i use my `property` file. The program is creating the file, but cannot read or edit it. I used some solutions from StackOverflow, but without success. Here is where i first call the `Properties` class:

```
public Manuals() throws IOException{
        // Check config file for first startup
        configFile = new Properties();
        Properties configFile = new Properties(); 
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
            configFile.load(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Manuals.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        curPdf = new ArrayList();
        addPdf = new ArrayList();
        allPdf = new ArrayList();

        this.search = "";

    }
```

Comment: And where is your `config.properties` file? The code you wrote expects it to be in current directory (usually the directory from which you call the `java` program)

Comment: When entering this, the file will be created automatically?

Comment: No it won't. You said that the program creates the file, but your code doesn't, are you using the `store` method before calling `load`?

Comment: this is the `constructor` and no, i'm not calling `store` before `load`

Comment: `FileInputStream` tries to open the file, so it expects it to exist (do you imagine the nightmare that would be if it decided to create it by itself if it did not found it?)

Comment: What you did will not create the file. Steps are: create a `Properties` object, `put` some properties in it, and then call `store`. When you want to load values from it, you can use `load` and `get`.

Comment: Still not working, i call `new Properties()`, `setProperty(string)` and then `store`. now I got the second part of the error (`main`)

Comment: That is a different issue/bug that affects parts of the code that you have not written in your question. The original question was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the stack trace literally screams in your face: the file has to be created before accessing it with [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Instead of merely logging the exception you could create the file. But it would be cleaner to check it's existence because in that case `FileNotFoundException` is actually a container for multiple exceptions ([see doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.lang.String%29)).

I am thinking about something like this:

```
public Manuals() throws IOException {
    File physicalFile = new File("config.properties");
    if(!physicalFile.exists()) {
        physicalFile.createNewFile();
    }

    // at this point we either confirmed that the file exists or created it
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(physicalFile);

    Properties configFile = new Properties(); 
    configFile.load(file);

    curPdf = new ArrayList();
    addPdf = new ArrayList();
    allPdf = new ArrayList();

    this.search = "";
}
```